Trigger first time OTP Email via MS Graph Api
We implemented our own signup and creating users in Entra External Id via Microsoft Graph API. In the default signup of Entra, an OTP Mail will be created for the first sign in. Is there a way to trigger exactly this mail from the Graph Api?

To quickly answer your question - is it possible to send OTP email to the user using Microsoft Graph API when you have built your own registration process? No, it is not possible.
OTP code will only be send when you use either registration page provided by Microsoft Entra External ID or using the Native Authentication API.

I can trigger a OTP via the native authentication api to reset the password. For sign in it is only possible if the auth flow in entra is configured for otp
